# Converting 16-bit DOS .com assembly for use on 64-bit

Tags: assembly, windows-8, x86-16, fasm

I wrote few programs in assembly in flat assembler for 32bit windows xp. But now that I have 64bit windows 8 I can't run the .com files, as they appear to be incompatible with 64bit version (the programs are 32bit).

How do I convert it so I can run it in win8 as well? Maybe use a different assembler?

I'd like to avoid the need for emulators and virtual machines.

Comment: Coding is similar enough, but the API that COM files run against - specifically, int21h and other interrupts - won't work on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Google: "fasm 64bit exe" suggests that FASM support forum `flat assembler > Windows > Hello world on x64` has an answer, see http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=14034

Comment: related: [16-bit Assembly on 64-bit Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3620670)

Comment: Related: [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1029093) for 32-bit examples of calling WinAPI functions in kernel32.dll

Comment: @PeterCordes How did you even find this old post? :D

Comment: google, for `site:stackoverflow.com windows ".com"`, or something.  Looking for dup-targets for a recent question about running a .com on 64-bit Windows got me started looking at cleaning up related questions.

Comment: @PeterCordes damn I better delete all my old questions so I don't get banned for duplicates xd

Comment: Having your question closed as a duplicate [isn't a negative against you at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265843).  I'm not downvoting the old stuff I find (unless it's bad), just adding links between related stuff so people who search and find this question or one of the others will have more info.

Comment: @PeterCordes I guess that can be useful. Although I wouldn't bother with questions that have so few views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .com file is 16-bit. You can use 32-bit instructions and registers, but it's 16-bit code. A 64-bit CPU, once it's put in "long mode", does not support vm86 which is what XP uses to run .com files. Blame AMD, not MS (this time). Use an emulator (DosBox, etc.) or convert your code to 32-bit (which should run on a 64-bit OS)

Comment: I can use 32bit instructions and registers in 16bit files? Interesting... Anyway I already said I'd like to avoid using emulators, so how do you suggest I convert it?

Comment: I'm  not that familiar with Fasm. `format PEexe` or some such, I think.

Comment: I should expand that to say that if you use DOS interrupts (which you almost certainly do), you'll have to convert 'em to Win APIs. "How" is beyond the scope of a comment. You may find you like emulators better than the alternative.